# Creality Ender 3 EZABL bed levelling not working

Tags: creality-ender-3, bed-leveling, ezabl

I've been pulling my hair out for the last couple of weeks with trying to get a decent print out of my Ender 3.

I recently bought [this](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/2-Pin-Z-End-ABL-Auto-Bed-Levelling-KIT-for-Anet-A2-A6-A8-E10-E12-Creality-Ender/223436573996?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2060353.m2749.l2649) auto bed levelling kit and these [solid bed mounts](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B083GLHGQ2/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) for my Ender 3. I followed this [Teaching Tech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jARw5_w0uGM) video as a guide to install the EZABL.

I used a spirit level and noticed the X-Gantry was a bit off. That's now been remedied with the trusty allen key. Everything else to my eye, and the spirit level, appears to be ok.

Another thing I noticed was that when the Z-Offset was adjusted to say the highest part of the bed, it wouldn't print in the lower part. This was also true of the reverse. Does this mean that the bed is too distorted?

This is the latest bed level visualisation:
[image]

Since the `upgrade` the prints have been all over the place. Parts of the bed is still too close to print at all and other parts are much so far away that the prints are weak and malleable.

There is also a lot of 'stringing' type behaviour going on.

See photo below and [this video](https://photos.app.goo.gl/o4riHZJof1mcuKNt8) for an example:

[image]

As I say, a lot of hair pulling has been going on so any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand how those bed mounts are supposed to work...

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I think the idea is that you won't have to readjust them over time like you do with springs

Comment: No, I understand the claim. I don't understand mechanically how they're supposed to work at all though (independent of the claim). I'm probably missing something but they look like a bs product.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE well they've not helped me haha.

Comment: It looks to me like they'd just make it impossible to adjust the bed, peg its height to the height of the bracket it's mounted on. Which is bogus. You need to be able to adjust it to get it level and non-warped.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE I think TH3D came up with that glorious idea: https://www.th3dstudio.com/product/cr-10solidmounts/
You're supposed to never level the bed, and let (their) ABL do everything.

Comment: Ok, if what @towe said is the case just remove these things and put back the original mounts; they can't work. You absolutely need to be able to adjust the 4 points to be coplanar. Only beyond that can ABL take over.

Comment: @R..GitHubSTOPHELPINGICE ok, i'll give that a try but yeah I was under the assumption that the ABL would take care of all my bed levelling for me. obviously wrong on that haha

Comment: @jampez77: ABL can't make a non-flat surface flat. You will necessarily have non-flat bottom-surfaces of any large print if your bed is not flat, which is what your image shows. ABL *should* be able to make an initial layer stick to a non-flat surface, giving you poor-quality prints (dimensional errors) instead of failed prints that don't adhere to the bed and pop off or string all over the place, but that's a very low standard to aspire to and not one I'd be happy to accept.